# Difference in timestamps from Oracle through JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I kept the dbtimezone in the Oracle DB(12.2) as '-07:00' and 'America/Los_Angeles' and retrieved a column with 'TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE' which gave me different values. It shows difference of 8 minutes. Please find below the queries.

```
ALTER DATABASE ORCL SET TIME_ZONE='America/Los_Angeles';
```

shutdown and startup

create user and create a table with `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

```
create table t_ts(id int, ts timestamp with local time zone, tst timestamp with time zone);
insert into t_ts values(1, timestamp '0912-02-29 02:02:10.089', timestamp '0912-02-29 02:02:10.089');
```

I send a query and got the row using JDBC and it gives me:

```
ID: 1
Epoch time: -33381730189911
TS: 0912-02-29 01:10:10.089
```

Now I drop the table and user, and then I set the dbtimezone to '-07:00' and do the same. It gives me different result.

```
ID: 1
Epoch time: -33381730669911
TS: 0912-02-29 01:02:10.089
```

I have two questions:

1) How can I disable the daylight saving while bringing the timestamps using JDBC.(The One hour difference is because the given time falls under DST)

2) Why the difference of 8 minutes in time?

JDBC version:

```
Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_91 on Tue_Dec_13_06:08:31_PST_2016
```

My JDBC code is below:

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from t_ts");
while(rs.next()) {
   System.out.println("ID: " + rs.getInt("id"));
   Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("ts");
   System.out.println("Epoch time: " + ts.getTime());
   System.out.println("TS: " + ts);
}
```

Comment: I am quite sure in 0912 (i.e. more than 1000 years ago!) there was no DST at all.

Comment: What is the purpose to have `DBTIMEZONE` value `America/Los_Angeles`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Then why it shows one hour difference if no DST?

Comment: `America/Los_Angeles` is also a timezone, is anything wrong in having it for DBTIMEZONE?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value from JDBC as a `java.sql.Timestamp`, as `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ` or as `java.time.Instant` or something else? Please add a [MCVE] including your java code so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: @MT0, I am using java.sql.Timestamp, I edited the post now. I also printed the epoch time. Thanks!

Comment: What is your `SESSIONTIMEZONE`? And what do you get by `DUMP(ts), DUMP(tst)`

Comment: What is the result in plain SQL? Perhaps Oracle time zone handling in database is smarter than Java `getTimestamp` function (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) which is also used by Oracle database.

For `America/Los_Angeles` you see this entry:

> From Paul Eggert (2018-03-20):
>   Dowd's proposal left many details unresolved, such as where to draw
>   lines between time zones.  The key individual who made time zones
>   work in the US was William Frederick Allen - railway engineer,
>   managing editor of the Travelers' Guide, and secretary of the
>   General Time Convention, a railway standardization group.  Allen
>   spent months in dialogs with scientific and railway leaders,
>   developed a workable plan to institute time zones, and presented it
>   to the General Time Convention on 1883-04-11, saying that his plan
>   meant "local time would be practically abolished" - a plus for
>   railway scheduling.  By the next convention on 1883-10-11 nearly all
>   railroads had agreed and it took effect on 1883-11-18.  That Sunday
>   was called the "day of two noons", as some locations observed noon
>   twice.  Allen witnessed the transition in New York City, writing:
>
> I heard the bells of St. Paul's strike on the old time.  Four
>     minutes later, obedient to the electrical signal from the Naval
>     Observatory ... the time-ball made its rapid descent, the chimes
>     of old Trinity rang twelve measured strokes, and local time was
>     abandoned, probably forever.
>
> Most of the US soon followed suit.  See:
>   Bartky IR. The adoption of standard time. Technol Cult 1989 Jan;30(1):25-56.
>    https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3105430
>
> ```
> # Rule    NAME    FROM    TO  TYPE    IN  ON  AT  SAVE    LETTER
> Rule  CA  1948    only    -   Mar 14  2:01    1:00    D
> Rule  CA  1949    only    -   Jan  1  2:00    0   S
> Rule  CA  1950    1966    -   Apr lastSun 1:00    1:00    D
> Rule  CA  1950    1961    -   Sep lastSun 2:00    0   S
> Rule  CA  1962    1966    -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
> # Zone    NAME        GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
> Zone America/Los_Angeles -7:52:58 -   LMT 1883 Nov 18 12:07:02
>           -8:00   US  P%sT    1946
>           -8:00   CA  P%sT    1967
>           -8:00   US  P%sT
> ```

You see before November 18, 1883 time zone `America/Los_Angeles` was not `UTC-08:00` but `UTC-07:52` (Time zone offset of UTC consider only Hours/Minutes but no seconds)

When you enter `timestamp '0912-02-29 02:02:10.089'` into a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column then Oracle actually executes

```
FROM_TZ(timestamp '0912-02-29 02:02:10.089', SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

You entered date `0912-02-29` which is before 1883 but I don't know exactly why you get the difference in the result. Perhaps at certain point Oracle ignores that `America/Los_Angeles` was not equal to `UTC-08:00` before 1883 - one could consider this as a bug.

Anyway, Oracle recommends to set `DBTIMEZONE = UTC`, anything else does not make any sense in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this answers my 2nd question. Any thoughts on one hour difference?

Comment: @Srikanth Use a `SESSIONTIMEZONE` which does not apply DST, i.e. `+08:00` instead of `America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate? where to use sessiontimezone?

Comment: Use `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '...';`. When you work with `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` then `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is actually the most important setting.